# SQL Server Left join to another data source

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010

I'm currently querying an SQL server database but I would like to know if it is possible to left join this to a Microsoft Access database?

Connection

```
DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=location1\testdatabase;UID=username;;APP=Microsoft Office2010;WSID=DS34245;DATABASE=ONE
```

SQL

```
select * from ONE.dbo.types types
```

The database I want to join to is:

```
C:\Documents\Databases\help.accdb
```

Comment: This [LINK](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1480/configure-microsoft-access-linked-tables-with-a-sql-server-database/) can help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect MS ACCESS use `Ad hoc links`

```
 OPENROWSET('providername', 'datasource', 'username', 'password', object)
```

Read the data like this

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'C:Program FilesMicrosoft OfficeOffice11Office11SamplesNorthwind.mdb';
'admin';'', Employees)
AS EmployeesFromAccess
```

More Detail [See Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-do-i-query-foreign-data-using-sql-servers-linked-servers/). Its might be help you